# Check internet connection on iphone doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, connection

I've tried many code to check internet connectivity from Apple docs and other sources.

The problem is that if the address is google.com return `TRUE`, if it's gydsddsds.com return `FALSE`, but if I disconnect my PC from Internet it return again `TRUE`!

Have you got a really working method please?

Comment: How did you exactly try to check the connectivity?

Comment: is this the same question you just asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001253/wifi-on-iphone-simulator

Comment: Check This Link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Use reachability class . It checks the network connectivity