# Using reachability on Iphone simulator and no wifi

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, reachability

I am using Reachability in my IOS app to determine a connection.

Following from this post [wifi on iphone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001253/wifi-on-iphone-simulator)

If the wifi is turned off the internet connection for the simulator is not available but the phone is still connected to Wifi therefore a connection has not changed. This is all fine and understood and of course I can test on the device itself.

However, I am looking to handle the error that a user is connected to wifi but the wifi has no internet connection like the screenshot below.

I use reachability in the following way:

```
#pragma mark - ()
- (void)monitorReachability {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:ReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

self.hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname: @"api.parse.com"];
[self.hostReach startNotifier];

self.internetReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[self.internetReach startNotifier];

self.wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
[self.wifiReach startNotifier];
```

}

//Called by Reachability whenever status changes.
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification* )note {
    Reachability *curReach = (Reachability *)[note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
    NSLog(@"Reachability changed: %@", curReach);
    networkStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];

}

I am using Reachability for ARC from tonymillion's github here: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Does anyone know how I can handle this situation of connection with a better error?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**create following method in appdelegate to use it on any class.**

```
-(BOOL)isHostAvailable
{
    //return NO; // force for offline testing
    Reachability *hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(netStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I still get the same error implementing the above.
    
     Error 20606:1b03] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0xc3748e0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/user_login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/user_login, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSUnderlyingError=0xe0962c0 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.1.0)